# VBA - Automation Error - Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following (previously working) code which converts formulas to their constant values. I attached it to a form button on the spreadsheet. It was working fine, and then decided to break. I click on the button or run the Macro and a box comes up with "Automation error". Excel help describes it as a "Automation error (Error 440)".
I have followed the advice of forums, inserting "On Error Resume Next" statement in various places. I have tried recreating the Macro. I have tried some different versions of the Macro. But have not managed to fix it yet. How do I get rid of this error? Is it something similar to a try catch statement in Java and Python?

```
Sub RangeOfFormulasToConstants()
'
' Changes a selection of Formulas into their values thus removing the formula.
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Useful box"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    Rng.Value = Rng.Text
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I have other Macros which are currently working with the spreadsheet and form buttons. Detailed below.

```
Sub CopyFormulasNonCalculate()

'
' PasteMacro Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Ret = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a range where you want to paste", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not Ret Is Nothing Then
        Selection.Copy

        Range("C2:F2").Copy Destination:=Ret



            Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub

Sub CopyFormulasCalculate()
Dim Ret As Range
Dim RangeToCopy As Range

Set RangeToCopy = Range("H3:AF3")
'
' PasteMacro Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    Set Ret = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a range where you want to paste", Type:=8)
    If Not Ret Is Nothing Then
        RangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=Ret
        Ret.Resize(1, RangeToCopy.Columns.Count).Calculate

            Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What line has the error?

Comment: Sub RangeOfFormulasToConstants()

Comment: Which doesn't make much sense at all.

Comment: Step through it using F8

Comment: It will not allow me to proceed past the Sub declaration. Inserting a breakpoint with F9 does not seem to help either.

Comment: may i see your file?

Comment: Unfortunately not as it contains sensitive employee information, however I have other VBA macros which are currently working. I will edit my answer above to include these.

Comment: Please consider restarting your machine. Repetitious crashes can destabilize a VBA environment, particularly so when *On Error Resume Next* is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `Rng.Value = Rng.Text` without knowing what you are transcribing back to the cell. This attempts to take the *displayed value of the cell subject to formatting* and return it to the cell as a value. Essentially, you are getting what the cell looks like which is not necessarily the value.

Use `Rng = Rng.Value` or `Rng = Rng.Value2` instead. This takes the underlying value that the formula has returned and sets the cell's value to it.

```
Sub RangeOfFormulasToConstants()
    ' Changes a selection of Formulas into their values thus removing the formula.
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q

    Dim WorkRng As Range, xTitleId As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xTitleId = "Useful box"

    On Error GoTo bm_Exit
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range: ", xTitleId, Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    WorkRng = WorkRng.Value  'do it all at once - no need to loop through

bm_Exit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Rather than stumbling through errors for every inappropriate code line, this traps the error and shuffles code execution off to the *bm_Exit* bookmark where the environment is restored before exiting.

Comment: I rebooted, amended the code and it worked fine. Thanks a bunch.